# Failed to see remote desktop connection with microsoft terminal services(VB.Net 2012)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, remote-desktop, rdp

I created a form, right clicked on the toolbox to choose item and added "Microsoft Terminal Services Client Control - version 1" (this is the only Microsoft Terminal Services Client Control I found), added an instance to the form and named it rdp, and a button to connect when I click on it:

```
Private Sub btnConnect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConnect.Click
    rdp.Server = "MyXPO07"
    rdp.UserName = "MyUser"

    Dim Secured As MSTSCLib.IMsTscNonScriptable = rdp.GetOcx()
    Secured.ClearTextPassword = "MyPass"
    rdp.Connect()
    rdp.Visible = True
    rdp.BringToFront()
End Sub
```

But nothing happens, not even an error, and the rdp control remains blank.
Any suggestions ?? (I'm using .Net 2012)

Comment: No sign of you writing the *essential* event handlers for this component.  Like OnLogonError, OnWarning, OnFatalError.  So of course you cannot know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Thx Hans.. Plus I realized I didn't specify the domain name in UserName !!! sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry all, I didn't notice that I didn't specify domain name in my UserName "DomainName\UserName".
Sorry :$